# How to create pokeblocks+?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Which berries or combination of berries give you pokeblock+?

Is it chance based? Because I have had certain berries give me a normal pokeblock and sometimes give me a pokeblock+.

In any case a list of berries/recipes and their ability to create + pokeblocks or the chance to create them will be appreciated.

Comment: I recall in the past the quality of the pokeblock depended on the number of times to 'hit' the machine with the right timing. I don't have the games yet, so I can't be sure, but I doubt it's much different.

Comment: @Jerry - Now you just throw in 4 berries into the blender and the Pokeblocks just appear. The whole blending mini-game seems to have been taken out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGIr87k9L68#t=144) guide linked below, every Berry has a chance of creating Pokeblock+.

However, if you mix **one** off the following 'Super Rare' Berries in with any other berry types, you'll guarantee yourself a Pokeblock+:

- Spelon
- Pamtre
- Watmel
- Durin
- Belue

If you don't yet have access to these Berries, mixing any of the following list of berries will **always give a Pokeblock+ when mixed together**:

#### Red

- Occa
- Chople
- Payapa
- Haban
- Roseli

#### Blue

- Apicot
- Ganlon
- Coba
- Yache
- Passho

#### Yellow

- Liechi
- Chilan
- Charti
- Maranga
- Wacan
- Shuca

#### Green

- Kebia
- Babiri
- Tanga
- Rindo
- Salac

#### Pink

- Kasib
- Petaya
- Colbur
- Kee

#### Sources:

- [Verilsify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGIr87k9L68#t=144)
- [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/pokeblock.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to mix 4 of the same berries together and they make 4 pokeblock+'s.